# Delete the token before the cursor

Tags: shell, command-line

When using a shell we have the option to type in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to delete the **word** (actually is any sequence of characters without space) before the cursor. How can I add a similar behaviour, one that would delete only the last **token**, that would be just like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> that is implemented by the Vim editor?

To exemplify suppose the following line is typed. (Obs.: [cursor]` is the cursor position.)

```
ssh fulano@delta.afh.com[cursor]
```

Now follow the results:

Under El Capitan/Centos 7 typing twice <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> I get:

```
$ ssh [cursor]
```

Under Vim typing twice <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> I get:

```
$ ssh fulano@delta.afh[cursor]
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between control-w in vim and in the shell. Can you be more specific?

Comment: In the shell, the whole line is deleted.

Comment: Normally that's not how it works. In all sytems I use regularly, the default behavior is deleting one word only.

Comment: Really? Which shell do you use? I use El Capitan's Ubuntu's 15.04 and Centos7's default shell and none of them works that way like vim. I have no luck :)

Comment: Do you have some dot-files you setup in all systems you use? What is your shell? I use Bash. Works for me in El Capitan's Ubuntu's and Git Bash. One of the most common shortcuts I use daily.

Comment: El Capitan's and Ubuntu's dot-files are default.

Comment: Maybe not, because what I understand you want, is something I "just have", and always had, without any special configuration needed. So maybe you want something else than what I understand. In any case, I don't think I can help. It sounds like you might need to tweak `.inputrc`, but it's too hard to debug remotely, and I don't know it well enough

Comment: Using a vanilla Debian system `CTRL` + `W` deletes the last **word**, not the whole line. I agree with @janos, this is the normal behaviour.

Comment: Can you tell us the output of `bind -p | grep C-w`? Also can you tell us how you are using the machine - are you sitting directly in front of it or are you connected to it across a network?

Comment: The result, for both El Capitan and Centos 7, is : **"\C-w": unix-word-rubout**. I am using the machine in from of me, no SSH. I run Centos 7 using Virtualbox. When I use CRTL+W for the following line:

Comment: (Sorry I can't edit the comment. Continuing...)
ssh fulano@delta.afh.com[cursor]

Under El Capitan/Centos 7 typing twice CRTL+W:
`$ ssh `[cursor]

Under VIM typing twice CRTL+W:
`$ ssh fulano@delta.afh`[cursor]

Obs.: [cursor] is the cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have bash using emacs keybinding, which always seems to be the default, then. alt-delete to delete one bit backwards, alt-D will delete the part after the cursor. So, starting with:

```
ssh fulano@delta.afh.com
                ^
```

For a quick example with `^` as the cursor, we then get `ssh fulano@delta.com` after pressing `alt-d`, and `ssh fulano@com` after pressing `alt-del`.

To find other key combinations for things though, it can be worth looking for emacs cheat sheets if need-be. bash is the only reason I remember any of them (sorry emacs fans...)

nb, on this machine it actually works using backspace, and delete doesn't, so you may have to check. Maybe just this one though.

Comment: Thank you very much. It has worked out of the box for Centos7, but for El Capitan I had to enable _Use Option as Meta key_ (Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Keyboard). +10 for saying that the default is emacs keybinding. The problem is that, if I enable the Meta key I cannot type in the "\" character. Oh god!